# Python Recursion function, index out of bound

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I am trying to write a recursion function in python and after certain call it throws index out of bound. However, I am no able to undestand why?

Could someone help me understand ?

```
def find_combinations(str, remaining_char=""):
    print("find_combinations(%s, %s)" % (str, remaining_char))

    if len(str) == 0:
        print(remaining_char)
    else:

        for i in range(len(str)):
            chr = str[i] # at this line it shows index out of bound 
            remaining_char = remaining_char+chr
            str = str[1:]

            find_combinations(str, remaining_char)

find_combinations("ABCD")
```

**Error:**

```
find_combinations(BCD, A)
find_combinations(CD, AB)
find_combinations(D, ABC)
find_combinations(, ABCD)
ABCD
...
...
    chr = str[i]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: If you shorten `str` but keep iterating up to the length of the original `str` of course you'll go out of bounds.

Comment: Do you want permutations or combinations?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Permutation. Sorry for wrong method name.

Comment: In that case, it is a one liner, check my answer below!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, rename your string and char. Right now you're overloading `str()` and `chr()`

Your error comes from the fact that once you have removed things from the string, indexes matching the latter values in its old length will no longer be availible

```py
def find_combinations(strz, remaining_char=""):
    print("find_combinations(%s, %s)" % (strz, remaining_char))

    if not strz:
        print(remaining_char)
    else:

        for i in range(len(strz)):
            print(i)
            print(strz)
            chrz = strz[i] # at this line it shows index out of bound
            remaining_char = remaining_char+chrz
            strz = strz[1:]

            find_combinations(strz, remaining_char)

find_combinations("ABCD")
```

outputs

```
find_combinations(ABCD, )
0
find_combinations(BCD, A)
0
find_combinations(CD, AB)
0
find_combinations(D, ABC)
0
find_combinations(, ABCD)
ABCD
1
```

As you can see, list index `1` is out of range

Answer (score 0):

Look at what you're doing: consider a string of 4 chars.

```
    for i in range(len(str)):
        chr = str[i] 
        str = str[1:]
```

i  str

---

0  ABCD
1  ABC
2  AB
... and the next time you try to access `str[i]`, the string is too short.

Keep the original string intact; send just the truncated one into the recursion:

```
    for i in range(len(s)):
        chr = s[i] 
        remaining_char += chr
        find_combinations(s[1:], remaining_char)
```

You still have logic problems in your program, but this will get you through the next step.  I strongly recommend that you do three things:

1. See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
2. Use incremental programming -- write just 2-4 lines at a time, one small chunk of code.  Make sure that they work before continuing.  Part of the reason that you're needing so many SO questions is that you've introduced multiple errors into your function before testing.  You can't easily isolate the cause of trouble when you have several causes waiting to bite you
3. Research on line the ways that others have solved this problem; their guidance will likely be helpful in smoothing the remaining problems in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `for` line. You can remove it.

Just replace the `chr = str[i]` with `chr = str[0]`, and rename your variables as said in previous posts (`chr` and `str`).

It will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) which is a python provided function. The example below generates permutations taking all 4 characters in account

```py
import itertools as it
words = list('ABCD')
print(list(it.permutations(words, 4)))
'''[('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'), ('A', 'B', 'D', 'C'), ('A', 'C', 'B', 'D'), 
('A', 'C', 'D', 'B'), ('A', 'D', 'B', 'C'), ('A', 'D', 'C', 'B'), 
('B', 'A', 'C', 'D'), ('B', 'A', 'D', 'C'), ('B', 'C', 'A', 'D'), 
('B', 'C', 'D', 'A'), ('B', 'D', 'A', 'C'), ('B', 'D', 'C', 'A'),
('C', 'A', 'B', 'D'), ('C', 'A', 'D', 'B'), ('C', 'B', 'A', 'D'),
 ('C', 'B', 'D', 'A'), ('C', 'D', 'A', 'B'), ('C', 'D', 'B', 'A'), 
('D', 'A', 'B', 'C'), ('D', 'A', 'C', 'B'), ('D', 'B', 'A', 'C'), 
('D', 'B', 'C', 'A'), ('D', 'C', 'A', 'B'), ('D', 'C', 'B', 'A')]'''

print(list(it.permutations(words, 2)))
#[('A', 'B'), ('A', 'C'), ('A', 'D'), ('B', 'A'), ('B', 'C'), 
#('B', 'D'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'B'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'A'), ('D', 'B'), ('D', 'C')]
```